# Is it possible to set expiration time for HttpSession (Jetty impl)

Tags: java, jetty

I'm using Jetty's implementation for javax.servlet.http.HttpSession and I need to set expiration time in epoch time (unix time). I've googled it and didn't find any appropriate results. Is there any possibility to do so out of the box? Or is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: also I want to have a possibility to prolong the session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions don't have an expiration time. They have an expiration *timeout*. After `N` time of inactivity, the session expires.

Because of this, you'll be looking at implementing your own logic if you want to have your session expire at specific "wall clock time".

A simple implementation that comes to mind would be to put an attribute in the session containing the time of expiration, then having a filter check that on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if I will put timeout time as attribute then I should have a possibility to ignore "idleTimeout". May be it will be easier to use my own implementation of HttpSession?

Comment: That depends on how easily Jetty allows you to stick your own `HttpSession` in there. A custom `HttpSession` would be cleaner, there's nothing hard about my proposed solution with a servlet filter. The filter would then be able to do any logic based on timeouts or expiration times or anything else you decide.

Comment: Ok thanks then, now I will do a little more research and will start to implement task =)

Comment: It might make more sense to put a custom attribute in your session that indicates that its expired (or not).    Your code which uses `request.getSession()` could then invalidate the session if that attribute exists and is expired.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Your solution doesn't explain what magic would put the custom attribute in the session, and it would involve checking for it in potentially multiple places in the code. My simple filter solution would have both the time checking and the invalidation in the same place (the filter), so the business code won't even know that there's something afoot.

Comment: Be careful of the filter approach, you don't want the filter to create sessions when there's no need for one.  Only to invalidate existing sessions that might be accessed.  Also note that the Servlet spec has nothing that guarantees filter order, so if you have another filter that requires/uses the Session, you have no facility to ensure your new Session expiration filter will execute before that other Filter.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I never said the filter would *create* the sessions. You're making a lot of wrong assumptions. The filter order should be mostly irrelevant as well, depending entirely on what other filters exist and what they do.

Comment: Be sure you *only* use [`request.getSession(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-) otherwise you are creating sessions in the act of attempting to access it.

Comment: If another servlet or filter does `request.getSession()` after you, then you have had NO opportunity to add that attribute.  You most definitely never want a filter to create a session, as you enter into world of hurt if you have async processing, async I/O, dispatching via the RequestDispatcher, or any listeners registered on the various session aspects (invalidation, binding, activation, etc...)  You'll just be fighting the rest of the application and the default servlet tooling.